# Sourcetree - Changing branch folder delimiter

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree for Git source control, and I noticed that it'll categorize branches into folders depending on where `/` characters are found in the branch name, e.g. `feature/DEV-111` will be represented as `feature -> DEV-111` in SourceTree, where `feature` is a folder. I'd like to use another delimiter instead of `/` because of unimportant reasons regarding other legacy tools. Those tools don't like `/` being in branch names.

As another example, the branch `master/DEV-967` appears as so in my SourceTree installation:

[image]

I can't find documentation on changing the delimiter anywhere. Is this possible?